# Subsetting rows with sequence of values and identifying columns where sequence begins

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large dataset of this format. I would like to
a) identify those IDs/rows with the following sequence of values 1 - 1 - >1 - >1 anywhere between x1 and x10; and
b) generate a new variable ("event") that identifies the beginning of the sequence, taking the value X1,...,X10.

```
my_df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),
                    replicate(8,sample(1:4,8,rep=TRUE)))
```

For a), I have replaced values >1 with 2, then pasted the values from X1 to X10, and then filtered for the sequence 1 - 1 - 2 - 2. For b), I created the variable "event" using nested ifelse() to identify where the sequence begins. This works ok with only 8 columns.
Is there a way to increase efficiency for datasets with more columns?

I highly appreciate any pointers!

```
df_seq <- my_df%>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('X')), funs(ifelse(. > 1, 2, .)))%>%
  mutate(seq = paste(X1,"-",X2,"-",X3,"-",X4,"-",X5,"-",X6,"-",X7,"-",X8))%>%
  filter(grepl("1 - 1 - 2 - 2", seq))%>%
  mutate(event = ifelse(X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2,"X1",
                 ifelse(X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2 & X5 == 2,"X2",
                 ifelse(X3 == 1 & X4 == 1 & X5 == 2 & X6 == 2,"X3",
                 ifelse(X4 == 1 & X5 == 1 & X6 == 2 & X7 == 2,"X4","X5")))))
```

Comment: What result would you expect if the sequence appeared more than once in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexpr` to capture the first occurrence of consecutive `1`s followed by values greater than `1`, for example

```
set.seed(0)
my_df %>%
    mutate(event = regexpr("1{2}[^1]{2}", do.call(paste0, select(., -ID)))) %>%
    mutate(event = ifelse(event > 0, paste0("X", event), NA))
```

gives

```
  ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 event
1  a  2  3  2  1  2  2  4  3  <NA>
2  b  1  2  2  1  1  2  1  4  <NA>
3  c  4  2  2  1  4  2  3  2  <NA>
4  d  3  3  2  2  3  3  2  2  <NA>
5  e  1  3  3  1  1  4  1  3  <NA>
6  f  2  1  1  1  4  4  4  3    X3
7  g  1  1  3  2  3  4  4  2    X1
8  h  3  1  1  2  2  2  1  2    X2
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. However, the var "event" now shows the start of a sequence with a minimum of two consecutive `1`, followed by only one value greater than  `1`. 
For example, row 5 shows x4 as the start -> but does not include the sequence 1 - 1 - >1 - >1. 
Row 6 shows X2 as the start, but the sequence starts at X3.

Comment: @Lina aha, I see your point. please check my update